# Python 2.7 turtle onkey event causing a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
def PleaseStop():
 SomeWord = input("Which word?")
Screen().onkey(PleaseStop,"a")
Screen().listen()
```

Pressing "a" will make the program ask "Which word?" forever.

No way to stop it besides closing the program. How do I get `onkey` to call the function only once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the event bindings by [calling `onkey` with `None` as first parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#using-events):

```
import turtle

def OnKeyA():
    print 'Key "a" was pressed'
    turtle.Screen().onkey(None, 'a')

turtle.Screen().onkey(OnKeyA, 'a')
turtle.Screen().listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Print is fine either way, input() is repeating itself forever, even with none.

Comment: The turtle graphics window affected by `onkey()` is different from the console window from which `input()` reads, so there's no conflict here requiring the removal of the event hander.  What's needed are instructions by/for the OP about which window to type in, and when.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't solve the problem. Print is fine either way, input() is
>   repeating itself forever, even with none.

I believe @Acorn was heading in the right direction with this but the example provided is incomplete.  Here's what I feel is a more complete solution:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, mainloop

def OnKeyA():
    screen.onkey(None, 'a')
    some_word = raw_input("Which word? ")
    turtle.write(some_word, font=('Arial', 18, 'normal'))

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

screen.onkey(OnKeyA, 'a')
print("Click on turtle window to make it active, then type 'a'")

screen.listen()
mainloop()
```

Note that this approach is awkward, clicking the turtle graphics window to make it active, hitting 'a', going back to the console window to type your word.  If/when you move to Python 3, you can use the turtle function `textinput()` to prompt for text from the user without having to use `input()` from the console.